# Move email based on date AND category

Tags: vba, outlook

Why is the following VBA script not moving items based on date **and** category? It is moving items older than seven days to a different folder called **old**, however it appears the items it is moving are random, **not** items in the AFG category.

```
Sub MoveAgedMail()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objVariant As Variant
Dim lngMovedItems As Long
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim intDateDiff As Integer
Dim strDestFolder As String

Set objOutlook = Application
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' use a subfolder under Inbox
Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.Folders("Old")

For intCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(intCount)
    DoEvents
    If objVariant.Class = olMail Then


         intDateDiff = DateDiff("d", objVariant.SentOn, Now)

        ' I'm using 7 days, adjust as needed.
        If intDateDiff > 7 And objVariant.Categories = AFG Then

          objVariant.Move objDestFolder
          ' MsgBox intDateDiff
          'count the # of items moved
           lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1

        End If
    End If
Next

' Display the number of items that were moved.
MsgBox "Moved " & lngMovedItems & " messages(s)."
 Set objDestFolder = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Edit - Sorry my code is a rough work in progress.
If it is too hard to understand I can try and clean it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't put quotes around AFG.

```
 If intDateDiff > 7 And objVariant.Categories = AFG Then
```

becomes

```
 If intDateDiff > 7 And objVariant.Categories = "AFG" Then
```

My bad.